# How to write individual dots to WPF control C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, graphics

I have a byte array `data` and I have a window with XAML.
I want to write white dots on a black element (can be anything as long as it's black; currently it's a rectangle).
I want to write one dot in a column (1 column width = 1 pixel) and then move on to the next element in the array and draw in the next column.

I have a piece of code that loops through the `data` array. After drawing a dot it increments the counter and moves to the next column. When it reaches the right side of the control, it jumps back to the beginning and continues with the array, but it also clears the column, so that it wouldn't contain more than one dot.

```cs
int width = (int)thingToWriteOn.ActualWidth;
int height = (int)thingToWriteOn.ActualHeight; //in my case it should be exactly 255.
int counter = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
{
    //fill the column with black in case there is already a white dot
    FillWithBlack(counter, 0, counter, 255); //startLeft, startBottom, endLeft, endBottom
    
    //write a white dot
    WriteDot(counter, data[i]); //left, bottom
    
    if (counter >= width)
        counter = 0;
}
```

probably these two are the most important things:

> I want to see the dot updates **instantly** PLUS I want to write
> about **500 or more dots in a second** so it has to be fast

I don't really want to keep the UI thread busy if it's possible

**In the picture, I have a 7-pixel high rectangle however in practice it would be 255 high.**

What I've tried:
Add 1 pixel long lines (as children) and then remove them, but it was terribly slow.

I would really appreciate an example with an explanation and code.
Thank you in advance.

[image: Pixel write example result]

Comment: Take a look at WriteableBitmap or the WriteableBitmapEx library.

Answer (score 1):

XAML code

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="Auto" Width="800">
   
    <ScrollViewer MaxHeight="400" MaxWidth="800">
        <Canvas x:Name="BlackCanvas"  
                Background="Black"
                >
        </Canvas>
    </ScrollViewer>
    
</Window>
```

Backend code:

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
int dotSize = 3;

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DrawDots();
}

private void DrawDots()
{
    byte[] data = new byte[1000];
    new Random().NextBytes(data);

    foreach(var element in data.Select((value, i) => (value, i)))
    {
        var column = element.i;
        var row = Convert.ToInt16(element.value);

        var pixel = new Rectangle();
        pixel.Fill = Brushes.White;
        pixel.Width = dotSize;
        pixel.Height = dotSize;

        this.BlackCanvas.Children.Add(pixel);
        Canvas.SetLeft(pixel, column*dotSize);
        Canvas.SetTop(pixel, row*dotSize);
    }
}
```

}

[image: this is how it looks]

Comment: Thank you, it works, however, it's still quite slow, so I'll be looking for a faster solution.